# NetBeans Test File and Run file diff

Tags: java, netbeans

In Netbeans after creating program and want to run a file, right click the mouse and two options are enabling,one is Test file and another one is run file. What is the difference, because i get confused so many times.

Answer (score 1):

In Netbeans, `Run` may have different meanings depending on the type of project you're working on.

In a Java project, `Run file` with a green arrow means running the `main` method of a Java class. 
You may even notice that the `Run file` option is grayed out if a class has not a `main` method.

In a Web or Enterprise project it means deploying the project to an associated application or web server.

The `Test` option means running any test cases for an individual file at a time or to an entire project at once. The tests cases are usually created with a Unit Test library like JUnit or TestNG. If you don't know what a unit test is you may like to read this for [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing).

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I guess from your question that you want to code some `c++` or `java` kind of program and you want to run them individually.
So, I suggest you to use special editor for every kind of development.
Netbeans generally used for big developments (but u can use it for a single file as well) and it helps in so many other aspects...(which I suppose you don't require).